# Are there any example of CSS hacks which were working before but not after new version or patch released?

Tags: css

Are there any example of CSS hacks which were working before new version or patch released?

Is it ever happened?

mainly i want to know for IE, but would like to know cases of other browsers also.

**my question is not about "CSS hacks vs IE conditional css"**

Comment: what will you do with them if they are no more applicable? and by the way using hacks is not a good idea.

Comment: i just want to know if there is any for as proof of hacks are bad

Comment: IE conditional comments are better than CSS hacks. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html Just include an extra css `<link>` inside the comment and away you go, coding just for IE.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley - I know this but this is not related to my question. my question is not about "CSS hacks vs IE conditional css"

Comment: It is about proving that CSS hacks are bad. Proving that there is an alternative that is better, is one way to do that. But you are still right, which is why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are. On the page [CSS Compatibility in Internet Explorer 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250496.aspx) you can find six examples of CSS hacks that stopped working when IE7 was released.

Comment: you mean these hacks are not working in IE but will work in IE6

Comment: @Guffa - but hacks are still working http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

Comment: Yes, of course they still work for older versions, but they changed meaning when IE7 was released.

Comment: @metal: If that is your definition of "working", then no, there is no hack that ever has or ever will stop "working" for any reason at all. They will always have some effect in some browser.